# Windows Server 2008 user account login problem in Vista

Tags: windows-server-2008, domain-name-system, windows-vista, login

I got working domain and all the user accounts log into Windows XP without any problem, but once I want to login into Vista with the same user accounts I got error message which says that the attempt to recognize the name of DNS domain controller failed. And I'm asked to check if the client is configured for access to DNS server. Can anybody help. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Well,

1. logon to the Vista box somehow and check its DNS settings
2. see if you can ping the DNS server by IP
3. try nslookup yourdomain.com to see if you can resolve your domain
4. try nslookup yourDC.yourdomain.com to see if you can resolve a DC
5. ping yourDC.yourdomain.com to see if can ping DC by name
6. `nslookup -type=srv _ldap._tcp.yourdomain.com` to see if some underscored records there
7. make sure Vista is in that domain (sorry ... kinda the basics)
8. if all this working and still no logon to domain accounts, then make sure no firewalling in the way between Vista and DC; or perhaps Vista's firewall blocking outbound traffic?